# What is meant when saying "the partial derivative operator $\partial/\partial x^\mu$ is a covariant vector"?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, tensor-calculus, covariance

Reading Weinberg's *Gravitation and Cosmology,* I came across the sentence (p.115, above equation (4.11.8))

> *The partial derivative operator $\partial/\partial x^\mu$ is a covariant vector, or in other words a 1-form, [...]*

Now, a section of $T^*M$ is called a covector field or a 1-form. Elements of $T^*_pM$ are called tangent covectors. In books about differential geometry I read that tangent COvectors are called covariant vectors. How do I have to understand the quote from Weinberg's book?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OP is formally correct that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}~\in~ \Gamma(TM|_{U}) $$ is a vector field (defined in a local coordinate neighborhood $U$), and *not* a one-form. What Weinberg simply means by casually saying that

> *The partial derivative operator $\partial/\partial x^\mu$ is a covariant vector, or in other words a 1-form,[...]*

is just that

> *The local basis of vector fields
>
>   $$\tag{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}  ~=~\frac{\partial y^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\nu}}$$
>   transforms in the same way as the components 
>   $$\tag{2} \eta^{(x)}_{\mu}~=~\frac{\partial y^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\eta^{(y)}_{\nu} $$ 
>   of a 1-form/covector [or a covariant (0,1) tensor]
>   $$\eta~=~\eta^{(x)}_{\mu} dx^{\mu} ~=~\eta^{(y)}_{\nu} dy^{\nu}$$
>
>   under a local coordinate transformation $x^{\mu} ~\to~ y^{\nu}=y^{\nu}(x)$.*

The point is that the (traditional) physicist often thinks of a $(r,s)$ [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) 
$$T~=~ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu_1}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu_r}} ~T^{\mu_1\ldots\mu_r}{}_{\nu_1\ldots\nu_s} ~ dx^{\nu_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{\nu_s}$$ 
merely in terms of its components $T^{\mu_1\ldots\mu_r}{}_{\nu_1\ldots\nu_s}$, and in particular, the transformation property thereof under local coordinate transformations. Local basis elements, such as, e.g., $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ and $dx^{\nu}$ are often viewed as merely bookkeeping devices.

In conclusion, Ref. 1 is probably not the best textbook to learn [differential geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) from. For instance, already in eq. (4.11.12) on the very next page 116 Weinberg claims that the fact that the [exterior derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) squares to zero, $d^2=0$,

> *is known as Poincare's Lemma.*

This is definitely *not* correct, cf. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms): The identity $d^2=0$ means that exact forms are closed, while Poincare's Lemma states that the opposite holds locally: closed forms are locally exact (except for zero-forms).

References:

1. S. Weinberg, *Gravitation and Cosmology,* 1972.

Comment: *Historically* the Poincare lemma is the statement that $d^2=0$. This is how it appears in most books written before the 1980's (For example Bishop and Goldberg's *Tensor calculus on Manifolds* or Flanders' *Differential Forms*). The local exactness theorem is then the "converse of the Poincare lemma".  It's only recently that that the theorem and its converse have had their names interchanged.

Comment: Hi @mike stone. Thanks for the historical note. That explains Weinberg's p. 116.

Answer (score 9):

Let $X$ be a vector field on a semi-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, then in local coordinates, the vector fields $\partial_\mu = \partial/\partial x^\mu$ yield a basis for the tangent space of at every point on the manifold.  This means that if $X\in TM$ is a vector field, then we can write it as a linear combination of the coordinate basis vector fields $\partial_\mu$ as follows:
\begin{align}
  X = X^\mu\partial_\mu
\end{align}
The components $X^\mu$ defined by this relation are called the *contravariant* components of the vector field.  It is then conventional to define *covariant* components of this vector field by "lowering" its vector index by using the components of the metric $g$;
\begin{align}
  X_\mu = g_{\mu\nu} X^\nu
\end{align}
Once we have made this definition, we notice that if we also define coordinate basis vector fields $\partial^\mu$ having raised indices as follows using the components $g^{\mu\nu}$ of the inverse of the metric:
\begin{align}
  \partial^\mu = g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu
\end{align}
then the original vector field $X$ can be written as a linear combination of its covariant components and the coordinate basis vector fields with raised indices;
\begin{align}
  X = X_\mu \partial^\mu
\end{align}
Now the question becomes, what does any of this have to do with 1-forms?  Well, given a semi-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, there is a canonical isomorphism between the tangent and cotangent spaces at a given point which we, as physicists, commonly refer to as "raising and lower indices."  In coordinates this isomorphism works as follows.  Using the covariant components of a vector field $X$, we define a one-form $\mathbf X$ by
$$
  \mathbf X = X_\mu dx^\mu
$$
Then the mapping $X \mapsto \mathbf X$ yields an isomorphism between $T_pM$ and $T_p^*M$ for each $p\in M$.  In other words, the covariant components of $X$ can be regarded as precisely the components that its dual 1-form has under the tangent-cotangent isomorphism.

When Weinberg says that $\partial/\partial x^\mu$ is a 1-form, he's being a bit loose with terminology (as is common in physics).  That object is really a vector field, but it is *dual* to a 1-form via the aforementioned isomorphism.

Comment: I don't think that's what he means. The section is about manifolds in general, no metrics are involved.

Comment: @MBN I never claim to capture what Weinberg "means" in the text.  Weinberg seems to identify p-forms with objects that "transform in a particular way" because they have lowered indices.  This is considered antiquated in modern physics, and I see no reason to propagate this idea, even if it is what he means.

Comment: No, my comment is that your answer is based on the assumption that Weinberg identifies vectors and 1-forms, as you can always do when there is a non-degenerate metric, and I don't think that is the case.

Comment: @MBN Haha look, I'm not making any assumptions about what Weinberg is doing; I don't so much care what's he's doing.  My response is a description of the standard method by which one identifies vector fields with one-forms in the context of modern differential geometry on semi-Riemannian manifolds.  In my view, the metric-based tangent-cotangent isomorphism is the best way to think about all of this.

Comment: Well, but you are making assumptions (or guesses). Look at your last paragraph. Your description of is fine, but it is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that he is not referring to the tangent vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$, but to a differential operator. Notice that he doesn't use plural, he is talking about a single object. Namely the 1-form valued operator, which maps each function to its gradient. Then you can form the wedge product with this operator and a $p$-form to obtain a $(p+1)$-form, which is the exterior derivative of the original $p$-form. This is the way he defines exterior derivatives. The wedge product is introduced in the previous paragraphs. This seems like a strange choice of notations and definitions, but it may have been fairly standard at the time.

About Poincare's Lemma (since Qmecanic mentioned it): I have seen a number of places where $d^2=0$, for the exterior derivative,  is called the Poincare's lemma, for example the reference, which Weinberg gives, Flanders, H. "Differential forms with Applications to the Physical Sciences".