# Intuition behind covariant and contravariant vectors

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, covariance

sorry is there any good intuition behind the following definitions. I am having trouble understanding these. Or is it recommended to just continue reading and accept these definitions for now?

[image]

[image]

Update: I think I roughly understand now, I took a look at covariant and contravariant transformations first. But any help is still appreciated :)

Comment: This might give you some more geometrical insight. The components of _covariant_ vectors are the _orthogonal_ projections on it's basis vectors. The components of _contravariant_ vectors are the projections _parallell_ to it's basis vectors. https://imgur.com/a/8H5TqEp

Comment: Related: [Covariant and contravariant vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79013/2451), [Is partial derivative a vector or dual vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144089/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change to coordinates to where the tick marks (units) are spaced twice as wide:

Contravariant vector, such as displacement, will then be measured to be *half as many tick marks*. This is opposite (contra) to the unit vectors which doubled in length.

Covariant vector, such as a gradient, will then seem to be *twice as steep per tick mark.* This is the same (co) as the unit vectors, which doubled in length.

Answer (score 0):

This is myself answering this question 2 years later. I still don't have a complete understanding of this, but when studying manifolds and tangent vectors this is much clearer. The coordinate changes correspond to different local homeomorphisms to R^n. And the coordinate changes then sure that the vector (or covector) on the manifold is consistent throughout different local coordinates. Read Nakahara, Geometry Topology and Physics's chapter on Manifolds for a clearer understanding