# Derive how $dx_\mu$ transforms for a coordinate transformation $x_\mu \rightarrow x'_\mu$

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, calculus

For a transformation of coordiantes $x^\mu \rightarrow x'^\mu$, the differential  $dx_\mu\rightarrow dx'_\mu$ transforms as   $$dx'_\mu=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}dx_\nu.\tag{1}$$

I am trying to show that this is true.

I started off with everything in covariant index and then raise the relevant indices: $$dx'_\mu=\frac{\partial x'_\mu}{\partial x_\nu}dx_\nu$$
$$dx'_\mu=\frac{\partial(g'_{\mu\alpha}x'^\alpha)}{\partial(g_{\nu\beta}x^\beta)}dx_\nu$$

What is the correct way to evaluate the term $\frac{\partial(g'_{\mu\alpha}x'^\alpha)}{\partial(g_{\nu\beta}x^\beta)}$ to proceed further?

Comment: May I know why this question is closed?

Comment: To reopen this post (v1) please use standard Einstein notation for super- and subscripts. E.g. coordinates $x^{\mu}$ are usually written with a superscript.

Comment: @Qmechanic May I know which parts are inconsistent? The notation I used is: repeated indices are summed.

Comment: @Qmechanic I had edited that.

Comment: Not edited everywhere. E.g. eq. (1) is not correct (v3).

Comment: @Qmechanic I am thinking of vectors being represented by $\vec{v}=V_\mu \vec{e^\mu}$, where the vector components transform  covariantly as $V'_\mu=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}V_\nu$. Thus for a infinitesimal vector $d\vec{x}=dx_\mu \vec{e^\mu}$, the components $dx_\mu$ transform as $dx'_\mu=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}dx_\nu$. Maybe I used the word 'differential' incorrectly in my question?

Comment: It is roughly the other way around. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144089/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry I'm not getting what you mean.

Comment: @Qmechanic Did you mean that I should correct eqn 1 to $dx'^\mu=\frac{\partial{x'^\mu}}{\partial{x^\nu}}dx^\nu$? I don't think that's what  I'm trying to ask if you mean that.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.