# Confusion about word "vector" in "basis vectors" of General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, tensor-calculus, terminology

If a vector is defined as a rank-1 tensor, it should be invariant under change of basis, while its components transform. So why a basis vector $\boldsymbol{e}_\alpha$ is called "vector" even though transforms $\tilde{\boldsymbol{e}}^\alpha=\partial_\beta\tilde{x}^\alpha\boldsymbol{e}^\beta$ as the *component* of a vector?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79013/2451

Comment: I STRONGLY suggest you watch lectures [3](https://youtu.be/mbv3T15nWq0) and [5](https://youtu.be/pepU_7NJSGM) from Frederic Schuller's General relativity lectures. Lecture 3 is about (multi)linear algebra (a subject which can be learnt completely independently of any general relativity), and lecture 5 is about tangent spaces, because it seems like you're mixing up several basic concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider a vector $V$ on a spacetime.

From general considerations of vector spaces, this vector can always be decomposed into a basis,

$$V = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} V^i e_i$$

with $V^i$ the *components* of the vector (real numbers, or if we consider a vector field, scalar functions), and $e_i$, a set of $n$ vectors.

Those basis vectors are indeed independent of the coordinate patch we're considering, we could define them even without defining one.

But in the general case, we do not consider an abstract basis for the tangent space. We consider for the most part what is called a coordinate basis, $\partial_i$. The coordinate basis is made specifically of vectors that are the tangents of coordinate lines. For instance, if we have some coordinate system $(t, x, y, z)$, the vector $\partial_x$ will be defined as the tangents of the lines defined by $(c_t, x, c_y, c_z)$, where every other coordinate is some constant.

If you pick a new coordinate chart, your set of basis vector $\partial_i$ will still be, in an abstract sense, invariant. The vector $\partial_x$ is still on the same point of the tangent bundle as it was before, so to speak, but that basis will no longer be a *coordinate* basis. It will just be a random basis that is unrelated to the coordinates you're considering.

But for this new coordinate chart, there exists a new set of basis vectors, which are related to the old basis by the usual formula,

$$\partial'_\mu = \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu} \partial_\nu$$

The basis vectors are indeed invariant, you are just picking an entirely new set of vectors.

Comment: So seems to me that you say: $\boldsymbol{e}_\alpha$ is a vector, because doesn't change when basis changes. If this is what you say, I seem to get it, but there is something still conflicting in my head about the fact of being invariant while basis (so itself) changes. Why the coordinate basis vector is represented like a partial derivative?

Answer (score 2):

I will present the same answer as Slereah, but by couching it another way perhaps I can add some further clarity.

Considered as a set of geometrical objects, the basis vectors are just that: vectors. Let's call them ${\bf e}_{(a)}$ where the index $a$ runs from 0 to 3.
And suppose ${\bf v}$ is some other vector.

When you change from one chart to another (changing your coordinates) none of the vectors change at all. ${\bf e}_{(a)}$ are still what they were, and $\bf v$ is still what it was. Of course they don't change, because by changing coordinates we are not doing anything to any of the vectors; we are just 'looking' at them from a different 'direction'. (Note: to get clarity here you should avoid the practice of saying that $v^a$ is 'a vector'; it is not: it is the set of components of a vector relative to some given basis.)

But what does change then? The essential point is that the set of vectors ${\bf e}_{(a)}$ always forms a basis, but it is not necessarily the coordinate basis. If these vectors form the coordinate basis for one choice of coordinates, then they do not for most other choices of coordinates. So what to do then? The normal practice is to write
$$
{\bf v} = \sum_a v^a {\bf e}_{(a)} = \sum_a v'^a {\bf e}'_{(a)}
$$
where the vectors ${\bf e}'_{(a)}$ are not the same as the vectors ${\bf e}_{(a)}$. Rather, they are the members of the coordinate basis for the new coordinates. So in moving from ${\bf e}_{(a)}$ to ${\bf e}'_{(a)}$ one is NOT transforming a vector. Rather one is replacing one set of vectors by another set of vectors. The operation of obtaining $v'^a$ from $v^a$ is ordinarily called a 'transformation' and that is a reasonable use of language. The relationship is the standard one,
$$
v'^a = \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^\mu} v^\mu.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer. I want to understand: what happens when I have a basis that is not the coordinate basis? I still don't grasp the importance of the latter